# Django - How to retrieve data from intermediary model in many-to-many relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following Models set up in my app:

- Lesson
- Student
- Evaluation

The Lesson and Student models have a many-to-many relationships through Evaluation.  In the Evaluation model, I also store the fee received for the lesson.  I know I should really store this in the Lesson model and then multiply by the number of students but sometimes for whatever reason a student may not pay the full amount for a lesson, so I need to keep track of it on an individual basis.

I'm trying to create a list of all lessons in a given time period and include a column which displays

1. The total amount received for the lesson
2. The total amount received for all lessons in that time period.

At the moment, I am just using a generic view to return all lessons and I have a simple method defined in my Lesson model which calculates the total fee received:

```
def total_fee(self):
    evaluations = self.evaluation_set.all()
    total = 0;
    for e in evaluations:
        total += e.fee_paid

    return total
```

However, I'm running the debug toolbar and this shows me that this view required 87 separate SQL queries when I ran it!

Obviously, I can't do that every time.  How can I fetch all of the data in one go?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would personally tackle this one using Django's [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/) functionality.  It's hard for me to conceptualize your database structure without seeing your models, but I think the call would look something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
total = self.evaluation_set.all().aggregate(total=Sum('fee_paid'))['total']
```

That should give you the sum of all the fees paid for everything in the evaluation set in 1 DB call, I think.  Take that with a grain of salt as I haven't tested it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, presumably this would give the total for all of them? Can it also be used for individual rows?

Comment: for individual rows look at the annotate functions.  [django-annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)

Comment: This will sum all of the column values for 'fee_paid' in all of the rows in the given queryset.  That would be the total of all the fees paid.  I'm not sure what you mean with your question about individual rows.  How could you sum 1 row? :-)  


If you mean it could work on another subset of rows, then yes.  Also, if you think this answers your question properly, please mark it as answered and give me an up vote.  It's appreciated. Thanks.